# I'm trying to print list of all the dropdown values , but i want to remove comma in the beginning of each line. How can i do this

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static ArrayList<String> getDropDownTextList(By locator) {
        List<WebElement> countryList = getDropDownOptions(locator);
        ArrayList<String> countryTextList = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for(WebElement e:countryList) {
            String text = e.getText();
            text.replace(',' , ' ');
            if(text.length()!= 0) {
                countryTextList.add(text.concat("\n"));
            }
            
        }
        return countryTextList;
    }[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKyqd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKyqd.png)
```

Apologies , I'm a newbie into programming

text.replace(',' , ' ');

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `", "` part which is immediately followed by end of string, you can do:

```
str = str.replaceAll(", $", "");
```

This handles the empty list (empty string) gracefully, as opposed to `lastIndexOf` / `substring` solutions which requires special treatment of such case.

***Example code:***

```
String str = "kushalhs, mayurvm, narendrabz, ";
str = str.replaceAll(", $", "");
System.out.println(str);  // prints "kushalhs, mayurvm, narendrabz"
```

***NOTE:***

Since there has been some comments and suggested edits about the `", $"` part: The expression should match the trailing part that you want to remove

- If your input looks like `"a,b,c,"`, use `",$"`.
- If your input looks like "`a, b, c`, ", use `", $"`.
- If your input looks like `"a , b , c` , ", use `" , $"`.